# VSCode: list enabled extensions in a particular workspace in Commandline

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to list enabled extensions in a particular workspace of VSCode in Commandline?

Comment: You can use `code --list-extensions` to list them all, but I don't know about a workspace

Answer (score 4):

No, this is currently not possible, as you can see when looking through the documented arguments in `code --help`. There was an unresolved feature request for this, but it did not receive enough upvotes:

[Code command line add a --list-enabled-extensions (#19083)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19083)

Comment: That feature request has now been closed (June 2020). Since there are no further comments on it I assume there simply isn't a way to do this.